# IceFaces 2 Problem with facelets example

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, icefaces

i tried to run the icefaces tutorial example on my home machine ubuntu it works perfectly in tomcat 7 but here on a windows its just giving me this nasty exception any suggestion?

```
GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.icefaces.util.EnvUtils.isPartialStateSaving (Ljavax / faces / context / FacesContext;) Z
at org.icefaces.component.fileentry.FileEntryFormSubmit. <init> (FileEntryFormSubmit.java: 47)
at org.icefaces.component.fileentry.FileEntryLoader. <init> (FileEntryLoader.java: 45)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just fixed this kind of Exception in my icefaces web-application. I had incorrect icefaces.jar file. May be you have to check all your jars?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was:
NoSuchMethodError: org.icefaces.util.EnvUtils.isCoallesceResources
The solution was to change in the pom.xml the version of icefaces that I was using, from 3.1.0 to 3.3.0